# How to do this Group By Query in Django QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

My Django Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = IntegerField()
    b = IntegerField()
```

I want to write a query set that answers the following question: "For each distinct value of `a`, what is the min, max and average value of `b`?"

How do I do it?

The SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT a, min(b), max(b), avg(b) FROM MyModel group by a
```

But I can't figure out how to to it with the `aggregate` and `annotate` methods. All the examples in the docs show how to use those methods when you are averaging on the same variable that you are grouping on.

Comment: just use a raw query. someone better at django may answer, but likely easiest to do for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Django aggregation framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min, Avg

MyModel.objects.values('a').annotate(Min('b'), Max('b'), Avg('b'))
```

The `values('a')` part here basically means "group by a".

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the `django.db.models` module has methods `Min`, `Max` and `Avg`. Is there any automated way to calculate the Median too?

Comment: @SaqibAli glad to help. `Median` is not a part of the aggregation framework. See more information and workarounds at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942620/missing-median-aggregate-function-in-django.